# facebook picture displayed by angularjs but warning error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made a angularjs app where i displayed facebook profile picture, like this :

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{comment.from.id}}/picture" />
</div>
```

Picture is correctly displayed: like `http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture`

But in console there is a error :

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/%7B%7Bcomment.from.id%7D%7D/picture 404 (Not Found)
```

So, because the picture have a redirection, this error is *normal* ?

Comment: use `ng-src` instead. This way you won't have a failing attempt to download from a not-yet-compiled link. Also, this is surely a duplicate, so I suggest you delete the question

Answer (score 4):

You're right, since you have dynamic variables inside the src attribute, the problem occurs while the redirection..

Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead

For e.g. :

```
<img ng-src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{comment.from.id}}/picture"/>
```