# Angular load my image two time when I am using an expression to create url

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular expression to create a url and require arguments, based on a few variable that are loading from different controller and scope. I am sure all argument are correct and when ever I am using the static url it is working but when I am using expression to create it something strange is happening and image loaded two time.

```
<img title="Original High Resolution Image" 
    ng-src="{{config.enterpriseUrl + '/ext/watermark/index.php?
        type=original
        &asset_id='+hit.id+'
        &srcFolder='+hit.metadata.folderPath+'
        &srcName='+hit.metadata.name+'
        &destFolder='+order.destFolder+'
        &collectionId='+ actions.newCollection.id}}"
    class="{{hit.watermarkClass}}"  
    style="height: 85px; float: left; margin: 10px 25px;" />
```

but it load image one time with static url like this that is created by the same expression:

```
<img title="Original High Resolution Image" 
    ng-src="{{'http://localhost/Enterprise/ext/watermark/index.php?type=original&sset_id=EWYmWSIjalt8V6A4OFDED5&srcFolder=/Test/permissiontest/PreviewOnly&srcName=drink glasses-64.jpg&destFolder=/Test/permissiontest/dest&collectionId=7zYQ1ePfqImAUSUmvo9vp1'}}"
    class="{{hit.watermarkClass}}"  
    style="height: 85px; float: left; margin: 10px 25px;" />
```

It causes to load of unnecessary hundreds of images every day. Appreciate any help to understand how can I avoid it.

Also I have tried this version and using bracket for each variable but it is still the same as using one bracket for all!

```
ng-src={{config.enterpriseUrl}}/ext/watermark/index.php?type=original&asset_id={{hit.id}}&srcFolder={{hit.metadata.folderPath}}&srcName={{hit.metadata.name}}&destFolder={{order.destFolder}}&collectionId={{actions.newCollection.id}}
```

Update 1: src is removed.

Comment: Why do you have a src and an ng-src. Normally you would only have one?

Comment: you don't need those interpolating brackets "{{}}" inside ng-src.. Remove them.. and also, don't use ng-src and src together. Use Ng-Src if you want dynamic urls. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581031/facebook-picture-displayed-by-angularjs-but-warning-error-in-console/27581058#27581058

Comment: About src you are right, I had a plan to load a preimage before main image but it doesn't work in this way and I forget to remove it. I have updated the code.

Comment: I have tried and and without {{}} it doesn't load images at all! If you check you own sample, you will see the writer is using it but in the middle of text: <img ng-src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{comment.from.id}}/picture"/>

Comment: It sounds like the value resulting from the angular expression might be updating in a watch cycle and causing the reload. Thats a lot of code to put inside `{{}}` to begin with. Why not move that into an angular controller and assign the result to a variable and use the variable in your `img` tag. If you still have an issue you'll be able to debug.

Comment: I have tried and added a function to one of existing controller to calculate that expression but problem is the same yet.